# How to execute and wait async functions in an non-async function which is called by another async function by using asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio to build a library for others. There is a situation that an async function calls multiple layers of non-async functions, and **needs to execute multiple async functions in the innermost non-async function**, wait for them to end and get results to complete the calculation.

How these internal async functions should be executed (functions in the middle of the call chain cannot be rewritten as asynchronous)? I found that I had to **create a new thread, then bind a new event loop created by asyncio.new_event_loop()**, and then execute asynchronous functions in it and wait for the thread to end to obtain results.

I wonder if there is a more appropriate way, such as registering asynchronous functions into the current event loop in a non-async function and waiting for their execution to end?